# Detect mouseMove out event for HTML canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, dom-events, event-listener

mouseMove event is for moving on the canvas itself, but I can't detect when the mouse leaves the canvas.

Is there an option to detect when the mouse is moving out of the canvas?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Have you tried `mouseout`?

```
element.addEventListener ("mouseout", myFunction, false);
```

Comment: For people struggling with this answer, the correct event is "onmouseout" not "mouseout"

Comment: @DavidBandel see documentation about `mouseout` here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseout_event

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of all mouse events that apply to html elements: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp (scroll down to Mouse Events).